# How to use jQuery to FIND & REPLACE given text with a matching URL instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey there, in short I'm looking to parse a web page and find the text "class abc" and create a url like this: http://www.site.com/code/documentation/classes/classabc/index.html

I'm basically gonna create links from my hosted svn code website to documentation I've generated via doxygen from the same codebase.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is great for handling objects and elements in the DOM and might serve as a starting point for what you want to do. This is really more of a basic JavaScript function however. Read up on JavaScript String Replacement [over here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: but I need to traverse the document in the first place and the text lies not neatly in an element. it's the word "Post" here as part of "class post extends...": http://svn.snacksquare.com/filedetails.php?repname=SnackSquare&path=/yii/demos/blog/protected/models/Post.php

I was using one of the nth-child jquery selector: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild#index  to get close, but I need like nth-child plus a next function that grabs the next piece of text after the selected element. I plan to just grab the name of the class and link it to the documentation generated by doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case no need for JQuery, Pure JavaScript language is enough.

[Replace Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

[Search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)